# Delphi - Simulate Click Animation

Tags: delphi, animation, click, mouse

This is my first post here on stackoverflow so forgive me for anything I'm doing wrong.

I'm making a kind of guide to the users without any computer knowledge of my application where I show him how to use it by signalizing what he should do, more specifically where to click. I want to that by moving a "fake" cursor to the button and simulate a click, and here is where I got my problem, I have to simulate just the animation of the click, and not the event itself but I couldn't find a way to do that, can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm sure we can help but we probably need a more specific question

Comment: What does your current code look like to position the pointer over a control? Are you just looking for ideas of how to let the user visually see a fake click?

Comment: How have you done the fake cursor?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz the fake cursor is a png image that I move from the center of the screen to the control.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge Yes, I just want a way to the user visually see a click.

Comment: Perhaps a transparent GIF animation would do the trick instead of a PNG

Comment: @Emerson - Use different pictures in succession then to make an impression that something is happening when the picture is on target. As you know a *click* does not animate, sometimes the clicked thing does. It would be more easy to animate the fake cursor.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz I'll try.
Thanks for the answers you all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're describing is exactly what `WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK` is for. It populates the message queue with the mouse and keyboard messages you want to occur, and the OS interprets them. In your case, activate the playback hook and perform the mouse events necessary for performing a click.

In preparation, you'll probably want to use `WH_JOURNALRECORD` to discover what messages you need. Once you have them, you can probably winnow them down to a reasonably sized list prior to shipping your product to customers. (In particualr, you'll probably record many more mouse-move messages than you really need.)

In your button's click handler, check whether playback is active. Only perform the rest of the event handler when playback *isn't* active. That way, your program will behave just as though the button were clicked (including any animation), but it won't execute the real event code.

Comment: Superb! I have never come across this functionality. +1

Comment: Good old Journal Playback. This dates all the way back to Windows 95 I belive. That was the time when most computers still struggled when playing videos. So at the time this was the most commonly used way fro teaching your users of how to use your application. But if my memory serves me correctly the journal system stores points location in scren coordinates which means that it becomes unusable when your application position or size is cahnged. I might be wrong on this but I do rmember that I had quite some problems when trying to implement this in one of my applications ...

Comment: ... In the end I eded up creating my own implementation of this which worked perfectly even if you would go and resize the aplication in the mist of playing the animation. Unfortunately the code for it is on my old laptop that fails to load up its OS most of the time.

Comment: To save modifying event handler code I would suggest uncoupling OnClick etc event handlers when the app enters 'playback' state and plug them back in when returning to normal.